# Access One Drive of disable users

Tags: onedrive

Can some one help me to understand what is the best way to retrieve someone's one drive after they leave the company?

Or what is the best practice for this issue?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

When a user is deleted, ownership of the OneDrive is transferred to that user's manager, or secondary admin (if no manager specified).  In addition, a Microsoft 365 Administrator will be able to view any of these files.  These people will have 30 days (by default) to retrieve files from the deleted user's OneDrive.

If you are one of these people, then you can access the deleted user's OneDrive files via the Microsoft 365 Admin center at https://admin.microsoft.com/AdminPortal/Home#/users

Reference:

- [Get access to and back up a former user's data](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/admin/add-users/get-access-to-and-back-up-a-former-user-s-data?view=o365-worldwide#access-a-former-users-onedrive-documents)
- [OneDrive retention and deletion](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/retention-and-deletion)